# Bootstrap Pagination Dynamically In ASP.NET MVC With Searching and Sorting

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, bootstrap-4

I tried Datatalbes.net but I don't want use any third party library.

Comment: if your question is if there is any building control or similar things in asp.net mvc there is not as far as I know. You can either use third party library or build your own

Comment: if you are using entity framework and LINQ which you most likely are then there to extension method you can use with LINQ, you can use .take and .skip methods you can read more about it in here https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Paging-using-Skip-and-Take-functions-in-LINQ-with-C-and-VBNet.aspx

Comment: You can also use .contain extension method for search

Comment: can you please  suggest me any third party library which is reliable and have MIT license policy. I want to use in my live project

Comment: datatables.net is a good third party library and its also free and open source under MIT license. this is from their website "DataTables is free open source software, available under the MIT license, and you are free to download it and use as you see fit.". If you want something other than datatable then this is a list of alternatives https://alternativeto.net/software/datatables/ if you want something that is not client side then try PagedList its in c# and could be used with asp.net mvc  i think https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/paging-in-asp-net-mvc-4-using-pagelist/